# Weit von sich weisen - reflexive pronoun sich

Tags: pronoun

I am using the verbal expression `etwas weit von sich weisen` and I am not sure about the form or declination of `sich` in this case, I would say for instance

```
Er hat die Regel des Abstands weit von sich gewiesen.
```

I would say this doesn't sound good

```
Er hat die Regel des Abstands weit von ihm gewiesen
```

when `ihm` refers to the same person as `er`. Is the first sentence correct and are there different approaches ?

Comment: If the second one worked, what would `sich` be there for at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence would be correct and sounds good to me!

> Er hat die Regel des Abstands weit von sich gewiesen.

You would need to choose the preposition `sich` as in `jmd./etw. weist etw. von sich`. It needs to be `sich` as you are speaking about the third person singular: herself, himself, itself, oneself (direct or indirect object).

Using "von ihm" would suggest there's a second person (not himnself), the speaker refers to.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the table [Reflexivpronomen](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Reflexivpronomen) once again.

While e. g. in plural first person *uns* is the reflexive pronoun as well as a personal pronoun, *ihm* is only a personal pronoun, so using it switches to the wrong pronoun type.